# Network Problem on 20.04.2 - Ethernets Off, Netplan Config Ignored, Segfault in Log

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, netplan

We have a small NAS server running Ubuntu 20.04.2 on hardware (i.e. not a VM), and the network suddenly died in a strange way yesterday morning.  I've been trying to fix it myself for over a day now, and not making much progress.  We didn't make any changes to the system config, nor to our network, but we do apply automatic updates and patches, and we did have some other device restarts, so I'm not sure what caused the problem to start.

The Netplan config (which was previously working correctly) bonds the two ethernet interfaces, and runs two different VLAN connections on top of the bond:
[NetplanConfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3rHu.png)

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# For more information, see netplan(5).
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp4s0:
      dhcp4: no
    enp3s0:
      dhcp4: no
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: no
      interfaces:
        - enp3s0
        - enp4s0
      parameters:
        mode: balance-alb
  vlans:
    vlan10:
      id: 10
      link: bond0
      dhcp4: yes
      nameservers:
        search: [xyz.com]
    vlan20:
      id: 20
      link: bond0
      dhcp4: yes
      nameservers:
        search: [xyz.com]
```

At boot, the two ethernet interfaces are "off" or "DOWN" and there's no indication of bond0, or either VLAN:
[InitialBootNetworkResults](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkSB7.png)

I found these logs referencing a segfault related to netplan.  It seems like they might be relevant, but I don't know what to do with these:
[NetplanSegfaultLog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4e1FI.png)

I can manually bring up the two ethernet interfaces using `ip link set enp3s0 up` and `ip link set enp4s0 up` but even after doing that, reapplying netplan has no effect - the `bond0` and VLANs still don't appear.  After manually setting the interfaces to `up` I can call `dhclient` and can get a basic network connection using DHCP, but it's on the wrong (default) VLAN.  I also tried changing the Netplan config to layer the VLAN directly onto the ethernet devices, but that doesn't work either.
[AfterManualUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6tG3.png)

I tried reinstalling the kernel (using `apt install --reinstall linux-image-generic`) and I also tried booting back into a previous kernel still present on the machine; neither produced any change.  I have made sure the packages are all updated.

Here is the hardware info:

```
---:~$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 00
       serial: b0:c7:45:9f:2d:9d
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=2.1-3 ip=10.0.0.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 memory:fe900000-fe91ffff ioport:e000(size=32) memory:fe920000-fe923fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: enp4s0
       version: 00
       serial: b0:c7:45:9f:2d:9c
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k duplex=full firmware=2.1-3 ip=10.0.0.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:17 memory:fe800000-fe81ffff ioport:d000(size=32) memory:fe820000-fe823fff
```

```
---:~$ sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx DRAM Controller (rev 04)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor D2xxx/N2xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #4
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #5
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #6
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #2
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 1
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 4
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 5
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) PCI Express Root Port 6
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #1
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #2
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB UHCI Controller #3
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller #1
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 90)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801JIR (ICH10R) LPC Interface Controller
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) SATA AHCI Controller
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 82801JI (ICH10 Family) SMBus Controller
02:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720201 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
```

Thanks in advance to anyone taking the time to read or make suggestions!

**Update:**
As requested from @heynnema, `dpkg` info for Netplan:

```
---:~$ sudo dpkg -l *netplan
[sudo] password for ---:
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  netplan        <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

I can't really make out what that means, but it did remind me that as a troubleshooting step I also previously tried to re-install Netplan, both via `apt get install --reinstall netplan.io` and also by directly download the .deb using `wget` and then `dpkg` to install.  Since the above doesn't reference version, I ran this, and you can see the version:

```
---:~$ sudo apt install netplan.io
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
netplan.io is already the newest version (0.101-0ubuntu3~20.04.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

**Update2**
Here is the corrected `dpkg -l *netplan*`.

```
---:~$ sudo dpkg -l *netplan*
dpkg-query: no packages found matching netplan.io_0.101-0ubuntu3~20.04.2_amd64.deb
```

**Update3**
See below, we've got a solution and it appears there's a problem with Netplan.io and Libnetplan verisons .101.  As suggested in the answer, I manually brought up the network interfaces and got a DHCP address in order to get internet access.  Then I ran this:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/netplan.io/netplan.io_0.102-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/n/netplan.io/libnetplan0_0.102-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libnetplan0_0.102-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i netplan.io_0.102-0ubuntu1~20.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo netplan --debug apply
```

It immediately fixed my problem.  I could tell something was different with Netplan via the `--debug` output; in previous tries it output about a dozen lines and mentioned all my interfaces, but this time it put out a lot more output, including parsing the full .yaml file.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dpkg -l *netplan*`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for your help!  I've added additional info to post.  Let me know if there's anything else I can provide.

Comment: Thanks for the info, however, you didn't use the correct full command that I gave. Please retry.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for your help, I've updated the post with the output from the correct command.  However, while working on this P.S.'s response below solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on my two web Hosting Servers. Normal dhcp4 network configuration. Segfaults when generating config etc.
Something is/was odd with the netplan.io 0.101 Update.
Fixed it by manually installing the 0.102 Update which is in proposal.
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/focal/main/proposed/netplan.io
https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/focal/main/proposed/libnetplan0
I started the network with dhclient, downloaded libnetplan0 and netplan.io and installed it via dpkg.
netplan try / netplan apply works afterwards

Comment: That is so frustrating!  But your answer immediately solved my problem.  I chose to grab these packages from archive.ubuntu.com just because I'm not familiar with ubuntuupdates.org.

This was so helpful - thank you!